# Can't install SBT using brew on Mac OSX Sierra because of connection timeout

Tags: scala, sbt

I tried to install sbt using brew on Mac OSX sierra but I got the following error:

```
brew install sbt
Updating Homebrew...
==> Using the sandbox
==> Downloading https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/0.13.13/sbt-0.13.

curl: (7) Failed to connect to dl.bintray.com port 443: Operation timed out
Error: Failed to download resource "sbt"
Download failed: https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/native-packages/sbt/0.13.13/sbt-0.13.13.tgz
```

I tried to ping `dl.bintray.com` but it is a timeout.

Comment: Might be bintray lag. Works for me, can you retry?

Comment: Doing this the couple of times starting yesterday, but no luck.

Comment: As an alternative, you could try installing paulp's "sbt-extras" script: https://github.com/paulp/sbt-extras#installation

Comment: Hi @dveim, I guess the issue was on the bintray lag, I retried it today and I can now install sbt using brew